# Using sscanf and sprintf in c++ - style

Tags: c++, c, styles

I was wondering on a style side of things if you think it is acceptable to use these functions in programs that are mostly c++. I ask since I have a professor teaching a c++ class whose examples are riddled with c-strings, string to c-string conversions, sscanf, sprintf, and other similar things.

Comment: `consistency matters` so as long as you stick to one its cool.

Comment: it's ok (if you want efficiency more then safety), but why not stringstreams?

Comment: `sprintf` should never be used, period. `snprintf` exists for a good reason.

Comment: The printf-style string formatting is very compact and convenient to use.  Even higher-level languages have an equivalent for it.  (eg. java: String.format; ruby: "%s %s" % s1,s2 )

Comment: @ForEveR Never seen that before.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: scanf is usually much faster than cin for some reason.  No idea why.

Comment: Probably bad implementation. I'm no fan of C++ myself, but there's no fundamental reason C++ code using iostream should be so much slower and more bloated than equivalent C using stdio; thus, the only reasonable conclusion is that the common C++ iostream implementations are just horribly bad in implementation quality.

Comment: @R.. The fundamental reason is that iostreams use the rather slow and bloated locale library for formatting. C using stdio doesn't use anything like that, and so isn't equivalent.

Comment: @Mike: I'm not sure what aspect of locale you're claiming is fundamentally slow. Even if there were operations that were slow in nontrivial locales, it should not be slow in trivial locales (e.g. "C" locale). I'll need more convincing evidence to buy the claim that it's anything but bad implementation quality making it slow and bloated.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: 1. C uses a loacale as well, although a much less flexible one. 2. IOstreams can be made fast but it requires a bit of thinking rather than just blindly coding down what the standard says. The key ideas to fast implementation of IOstreams are things like storing formatting flags and error conditions in one word (so you do one instead of three tests), caching results from facet calls, especially for ctype and numpunct, and treating `std::[io]streambuf_iterator`s to deal with segmented sequences. ... and, of course, not delegating to C's functions.

Comment: @R..: I'm not claiming any particular aspect of locale is fundamentally slow; I've just noticed that it involves a lot of virtual function calls (even if the locale is "trivial", whatever you mean by that), and features heavily when profiling code that does a lot of formatted I/O. That makes it seem more likely to me that that's what makes it slow. However, I can't offer the evidence you require; it is indeed possible (if unlikely) that everyone who ever implemented iostreams somehow failed to do it properly, but I don't care enough to demand evidence for that extraordinary claim.

Comment: @Mike: I claim I did a lot better than others, avoiding lots of processing! The implementation is somewhat aged and may not even compile (with mire stingent compilers) but it can be downloaded from <http://www.dietmar-kuehl.de/cxxrt/>. I'm trying to get a new version together improving further but I'm struggling to find the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's a few points on the general streams vs stdio issue to help you decide.  Most are applicable to `stringstream` vs `sprintf`/`sscanf`; a few only where buffered non-memory streams (e.g. files, stdin/stdout) are involved.

- streams are type safe so if your program compiles it will usually run ok, whereas the matching of stdio format strings to arguments and types is error prone and compilers are not required to validate it (though some can)
- if you end up mixing them, you'll need to use the `sync_with_stdio` member on your streams (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/sync_with_stdio/) - which could slow them down
- the standard C versions of `scanf`, `printf` etc. don't allow customisations supporting new types you create, which is incredibly limiting and frustrates you creating and using polymorphic code (e.g. templates, macros) that prints different types

  - some implementations like GNU's do have some customisation features
- `printf`/`scanf` style format strings can be more concise than C++ streaming - particularly when iomanip is used - but depend more on familiarity for readability
- most third party C++ code will only come with streaming ability
- in practice, `printf`/`scanf` are often faster despite needing run-time switching to type-specific handling, but that's at a cost: they lack some stream features such as locale-specific behaviour, behaviours persistent across calls etc.
- `printf`/`scanf` etc. can sometimes be used to vary runtime I/O parsing on the basis of configuration specifying format strings (this is easier with extensions like GNU's that allow you to refer to arguments using a number to indicate their position in the argument list, rather than having to have the format string and arguments correspond); still, this is fragile (with mistakes often crashing the program) and - for the oft-attempted use of internationalisation - not nearly as capable as facilities designed specifically for that purpose

Comment: `iostream` is not involved. These are `sscanf` and `sprintf` (note the **s**), i.e. string functions, not `FILE` functions.

Comment: @R: Fair point, thanks - I'm addressing the family of `printf`/`scanf` functions as per the "similar things" in the question; bit of a generalisation from strings specifically. Most of these points are relevant for stringstream vs `sprintf`/`sscanf` though.  I'll highlight that in my answer.  Cheers.